# Javascript Regex to Split a String by Word Boundary when not in quotes

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I've got an expression held in a JS string and I want to split it into tokens. The string could contain any symbols or characters (its actually a string expression)

I've been using

```
expr.split(/([^\"]\S*|\".+?\")\s*/)
```

But when I get a text symbol outside of quotes it splits it wrongly.

e.g. When

```
expr = "Tree = \"\" Or Tree = \"hello cruel world\" + \" and xyz\""
```

Then The OR gets mixed in with the following string.

Splitting on \b seems to be the way to go (is it?) but I don't know how to keep the strings in quotes together. So ideally in the above I'd get:

```
Tree
=
\"\"
Or
Tree
=
\"Hello cruel world\"
+
\" and xyz\"
```

I suppose ideally I would find a tokenizer but if I could do it in regex that would be a major headache solved :)

thanks

Comment: The `+` means at least 1 character, so it will never match `""`. Try a `*`.

Comment: short notice: i find https://regex101.com/ verry helpfull when i encounter problems with regex, as it gives short explanations on the regex parts

Comment: Thanks both, Kenneys answer looks promising, I'm just testing it out

Comment: Note that `\b` won't solve your problem here if you want to retrieve the `=` as a match : since `=` isn't a word character, there won't be any word-boundary around it.

Comment: My whole app just ran through kenney's answer with a zillion different cases and it works ! Kenney if you'd like to post it as an answer I'll mark it as answer - thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler approach is to use `.match()` instead of `.split()` and match the characters between the quotes *or* groups of non-whitespace characters using an alternation:

```
/"[^"]+"|\S+/g
```

Explanation:

- `"[^"]+"` - Match one or more non-`"` characters between the double quotes..
- `|` - Alternation
- `\S+` - ...or match groups of one or more non-whitespace characters

Usage:

```js
var string = 'Tree = \"\" Or Tree = \"hello cruel world\" + \" and xyz\"';
var result = string.match(/"[^"]+"|\S+/g);

document.querySelector('pre').textContent = JSON.stringify(result, null, 4);
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: Is there a way to tweak this regex so that the strings with multiple words don't include the quotes, or would I need to postprocess the results?